# Java Action Performed getsource()

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have a java code with 3 actions listeners corresponding to menus in my java page. When i click on a menu, i want a specific page to appear.

Here is my code ( when i click on a menu it doesn't work )

```
JPanel panContents = new JPanel();
PanCommander panCommander = new PanCommander();
PanHistorique panHistorique = new PanHistorique();
PanModifierProfil panModifierProfil = new PanModifierProfil();

public class PanCommander extends JPanel
{
    public void initialisation () {
       this.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }
}
//The other 2 pans are 2 other colors, when i click on a menu i want the page to change the color

//In the constructor :
    panContents.add(panCommander, COMMANDER); 
    panContents.add(panHistorique, HISTORIQUE);
    panContents.add(panModifierProfil, MODIFIER_PROFIL);

    //We say to our JFrame that our JPanel will be its content pane
    this.getContentPane().add(panContents); 
    //We initialise the menu
    this.initialisationMenu();

    //its code :
    private void initialisationMenu () {
      JMenuItem commander = new JMenuItem("Commander");
      commander.addActionListener(this);
      JMenuItem modifierProfil = new JMenuItem("Modifier Profil");
      modifierProfil.addActionListener(this);
      JMenuItem historique = new JMenuItem("Historique");
      historique.addActionListener(this);

      JMenu menuMonCompte = new JMenu("Mon compte");
      menuMonCompte.add(commander);
      menuMonCompte.add(modifierProfil);
      menuMonCompte.add(historique);

      JMenu menuDeconnexion = new JMenu("Deconnexion");

      barreMenu.add(menuMonCompte);
      barreMenu.add(menuDeconnexion);
}
//And finally my actionPerformed ( that doesn't work )
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == panCommander) {
        cartes.show(panContents, COMMANDER);
        panelVisible(COMMANDER); 
    }
    if (event.getSource() == panHistorique) {
        cartes.show(panContents, HISTORIQUE);
        panelVisible(HISTORIQUE);
    }
    if (event.getSource() == panModifierProfil) {
        cartes.show(panContents, MODIFIER_PROFIL);
        panelVisible(MODIFIER_PROFIL);
    }
}
```

If someone could help me that would be very nice of you !

Comment: The sources of the events are the `JMenuItem`s, not the panels .e.g `if (event.getSource() == panCommander)` should be `if (event.getSource() == commander)` .

Comment: I tried it before, it doesn't work, "commander cannot be resolved to a variable". Is it because I initialized them in a other method ?

Comment: It is a scope problem, declare your `JMenuItem` objects at the class level, not inside a method .

Comment: I'll try that, thanks

Comment: That worked ! Thanks